ionic angular where to put BehaviorSubject subscribe
In my ionic angular app I am using behaviorSubject to indicate when to refresh some data. Currently, the subscribe is put into the first tab's ionicViewEnter like below:
async ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.sharedSvc.getDataUpdateValue().subscribe(async(value) => {
      if(value === true){
        console.log("time to refresh data and reset variable")
        this.updatePassiveIncomeBreakup()
        this.updateDoughetData()
        this.updateBarChatData()
        this.sharedSvc.setDataUpdateValue(false)
      }
    })
  }

In this case is this gets called every time when the tab is switched being in ionicViewDidEnter. I am guess this is the wrong place as i need to subscribe to this just only once somewhere.
What should be the best place for that?

Why not ngOnInit called during component initialization and never again.
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedSvc.getDataUpdateValue().subscribe(async(value) => {
      if(value === true){
        console.log("time to refresh data and reset variable")
        this.updatePassiveIncomeBreakup()
        this.updateDoughetData()
        this.updateBarChatData()
        this.sharedSvc.setDataUpdateValue(false)
      }
    })
  }


yes but is somewhere else such as app.components.ts is a better place?

@MoblizeIT If the tab change does not destroy the component, ngOnInit of the component will be called only once and the listener will be done only once! If the app component is closest to the tabs, then sure!
